# Making array populations in functions instantaneous

Tags: javascript, arrays

I set an array
`let A1 = []`

then create a function to populate the array

```
function popA1() {
  let x = new Array(v1, v2, v3, vn);
  return A1 = x;
}

function basicTableGenerator(myArray) {
    let result = "<table><thead><th>Table</th></thead>";
    for(let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        result += "<tr><td>" + myArray[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    result += </table>";
    return result;
}
```

and that function is called by a button click

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (A1.length == 0) {
    popA1();
  }
  generateTableFromA1(A1);
}
```

It works well and all, except for the tiny fact that `generateTableFromA1()` won't work until the second time I click that button, how do I get it to work the first time?

Comment: Can you give us the code for generateTableFromA1? also, why does popA1 create x? Why not just do: `A1 = [v1, v2, v3, vn];`? And why does it return A1?

Comment: @KaiJ the array is generated from a REST API get method which is called once (to prevent stacking requests for no reason) and then depending on the function it could be an autocomplete based on the array, a single column table with simple trtd elements or a dynamic table generator, ill put a simple scaffold up for reference tho

Comment: Do you initialize `A1` somewhere before your call to `À1.length`?

Comment: @MoritzRoessler empty array A1 is called, the check is then to find out if it needs to be populated with the new data or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function popA1() {
  let x = new Array(v1, v2, v3, vn);
  A1 = x;
}
```

try to remove `return`